# Angular *ngIf multiple condition with 'AND' and 'OR' operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I've an `*ngIf` condition where I'm checking for negation using `||` (or) operator but along with the `||`, I also need to check for `&&` condition.

Basically I'm checking if `activeIndex` is not `0` or `2`. But now I also need to check for and condition like  `activeIndex` is not `0` AND `obj`(object) is `empty{}` OR  `activeIndex` is not `2`

```
<div class="lmn-my-0 lmn-py-0">
<ng-container *ngIf="!(activeIndex === 0 || activeIndex === 2); else otherSteppers">
 // if condition some code
</ng-container>
<ng-template #otherSteppers>
// else some code
</ng-template>
</div>
```

How can I add condition `activeIndex` is not `0` AND `obj`(object) is `empty{}`.

I tried below code but it didn't work. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, if no how can we achieve such condition

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(activeIndex === 0 && (obj | json) == '{}' || activeIndex === 2); else otherSteppers"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

check this out

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(activeIndex !== 0 && (obj | json) == '{}') || activeIndex !== 2; else otherSteppers"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*ngIf="condition1 && condition2 && condition3"
```

You can use this to check for multiple 'AND' conditions, and in your case, you can use this:

```
*ngIf="(activeIndex !== 0 || (obj | json) !== '{}') && activeIndex !== 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) also as shown below.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(activeIndex === 0 && !(obj | keyvalue)?.length) || activeIndex === 2); else otherSteppers"></ng-container>
```